# unable to load whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I'm unable to launch WhatsApp as every time i load the app it just keeps on loading and loading all through, I have tried reinstallation but all the same there is no change, the app can't open just keeps loading. I'm using Lumia 535 windows 10.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information such as the app version, OS build, whether you've tried reinstalling it, etc.